# Imprimir datos que pertenecen a un TreeMap

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, método, map

En el método `consultas()`, como podría imprimir el nombre del alumno y sus calificaciones?

Hasta ahorita lo que me imprime son direcciones de memoria, y no el nombre y las calificaciones.

**Nota:** El mapa que recibe dicho metodo, es un mapa que retorna un metodo llamado `darDeAlta()` el cual recibe los datos de un nuevo alumno.

```
class Alumno {

private String nombre;
private int matricula;
private double calificaciones[];



Alumno(String nombre, int matricula, double calificaciones[]) {

    this.calificaciones = calificaciones;

}

String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

int getMat() {
    return matricula;
}

double[] getCalif() {
    return calificaciones;
}

void setCalif(double calif[]) {
    calificaciones = calif;
}

}
public class Ejercicio {

Map<Integer, Alumno> alumnos = new TreeMap<>();  
  public Map darDeAlta() {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    //boolean b=false;

    double d[] = new double[5];

    System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del estudiante");
    String n = y.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca su matricula (de 5 digitos)");
    int m = y.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca las calificaciones: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca la calificacion");
        d[i] = y.nextDouble();

    }

    if (alumnos.containsKey(m)) {
        System.out.println("Esa matricula ya existe, ingrese otra matricula");

    } else {
        alumnos.put(m, new Alumno(n, m, d));
        System.out.println("Se han dado de alta los datos :)");
        System.out.println("Desea ingresar mas alumnos? \n");


        String s = y.next();
        //if (s.compareTo("si")==0 || s.compareTo("no")==0) 
           // b = true;


    }

    return alumnos;

}

 public boolean consultas(Map alumnos) {
    Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean c;

    System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del estudiante a buscar");
    int k = y.nextInt();
    c = alumnos.containsKey(k);
    if (c) {

        System.out.println("Los datos son:\n" +"Nombre del alumno: "+ alumnos.get(k) + "Calificaciones: " + alumnos.values());
        //System.out.println("Los datos son:\n" +"Nombre del alumno: "+ alumnos.get(k).getNombre() + "Calificaciones: " + al.getCalif());
    } else {
        System.out.println("El alumno no se encuentra");
    }
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código tienes varios errores.

#### Primero

En tu clase `Alumno` solo estas inicializando la variable `calificaciones`, por lo que solo podrás acceder a información almacena en esa variable. Si tratas de acceder a cualquier otra variable a través de los métodos `get`, no obtendrás nada, ya que no le estas asignando ninguna tipo de valor. Los valores que le pasas al constructor de la clase Alumno, se quedan en la nada, a exepcion del valor del parámetro `calificaciones`, ya que ese se lo pasas a la variable `calificaciones`.

Para asignarle valores a las otras variables, tienes que inicializarlas en el constructor.

```
Alumno(String nombre, int matricula, double calificaciones[]) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.calificaciones = calificaciones;

}
```

#### Segundo

Para obtener los valores almacenados en las variables de la clase `Alumno`, tienes que acceder a los método `get` de las variables, de lo contrario solo accederás al objeto Alumno y te mostrara "direcciones de memoria", como te esta pasando. Para evitar eso tendrías que sobrescribir el método `toString()` y dentro de el retornar un `String` en el que concatenes el valor de todas las variables.

Para acceder a los valores de las variables, utiliza los métodos get de estas.

```
// con getNombre() obtienes el valor almacenado en la variable nombre.
alumnos.get(k).getNombre()
```

Con `alumnos.get(k)` accedes al objeto de tipo Alumno, para que este se te muestre como un `String` sobrescribe el método `toString()`.

```
public String toString() {

    String alumno = "nombre: " +this.nombre+ 
                    ", matricula: " +this.matricula+ 
                    ", calificaciones: " +Arrays.toString(this.calificaciones)+ "";
    return alumno;
}
```

Con estas correcciones tu código se vería así:

#### Alumno

```
class Alumno {

    private String nombre;
    private int matricula;
    private double calificaciones[];

    Alumno(String nombre, int matricula, double calificaciones[]) {

        // inicializas los valores de todas las variables
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.calificaciones = calificaciones;
    }

    String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    int getMat() {
        return matricula;
    }

    double[] getCalif() {
        return calificaciones;
    }

    void setCalif(double calif[]) {
        calificaciones = calif;
    }

    // Sobrescribes el metodo toString() y retornas un String con los 
    // valores de las variables concatenados. 
    public String toString() {

        String alumno = "nombre: " +this.nombre+ 
                        ", matricula: " +this.matricula+ 
                        ", calificaciones: " +Arrays.toString(this.calificaciones)+ "";
        return alumno;
    }

}
```

#### Ejercicio

```
public class Ejercicio {

    Map<Integer, Alumno> alumnos = new TreeMap<>(); 

    public Map darDeAlta() {
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        //boolean b=false;

        double d[] = new double[5];

        System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del estudiante");
        String n = y.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduzca su matricula (de 5 digitos)");
        int m = y.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduzca las calificaciones: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca la calificacion");
            d[i] = y.nextDouble();
        }

        if (alumnos.containsKey(m)) {
            System.out.println("Esa matricula ya existe, ingrese otra matricula");
        } else {
            alumnos.put(m, new Alumno(n, m, d));
            System.out.println("Se han dado de alta los datos :)");
            System.out.println("Desea ingresar mas alumnos? \n");

            String s = y.next();
            //if (s.compareTo("si")==0 || s.compareTo("no")==0) 
               // b = true;
        }

        return alumnos;
    }

    public boolean consultas(Map alumnos) {

        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean c;

        System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del estudiante a buscar");
        int k = y.nextInt();
        c = alumnos.containsKey(k);
        if (c) {

            // Muestras los datos de los alumnos obteniendo el valor de las variables
            System.out.println("Los datos son:\n" 
                +"Nombre del alumno: "+ alumnos.get(k).getNombre() 
                +"Calificaciones: " + alumnos.get(k).getCalif());

            // Muestras todos los datos de los alumnos.
            // Recuerda que con 'alumnos.get(k)' estas accediendo al objeto alumno y
            // al sobreescribir el metodo `toString()` en la clase Alumnos obtienes 
            // los datos que retornas en el metodo `toString()`
            System.out.println("Los datos son:\n" +alumnos.get(k));

        } else {
            System.out.println("El alumno no se encuentra");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm..me marca un error, aqui `System.out.println("Los datos son:\n" 
                +"Nombre del alumno: "+ alumnos.get(k).getNombre() +"Calificaciones: " + alumnos.values().getCalif());`, especificamente en los metodos `getNombre()` y `getCalif()`. El error dice `cannot find symbol`

Comment: @Michelle Borra `alumnos.values().getCalif()`. Que tu codigo quede asi: `System.out.println("Los datos son:\n" +"Nombre del alumno: "+ alumnos.get(k).getNombre() +"Calificaciones: " );`. Prueba y me dejas saber.

Comment: no me deja compilar, porque marca el error en `getNombre()`

Comment: @David `alumnos.get(k)` devuelve un `Object` por lo cuál no tiene los `getters` que muestra su respuesta. Para obtener datos específicos _getters_ debe realizar el `cast` al tipo `Alumno` de la forma `((Alumno)alumnos.get(k)).getNombre()`

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta. El error era, que a `getNombre()` le faltaban los paréntesis y estaba obteniendo mal el valor de `getCalif()`. Ahora tu codigo debe de compilar.

Comment: @Dev.Joel me funciono este `((Alumno)alumnos.get(k)).toString()` gracias:)

Comment: @Michelle no es necesario hacer el `cast` para acceder al método `toString()` si ya lo sobrescribió antes en su clase , bastaría con `alumnos.ge(k)` el `cast` es necesario si desea acceder a los `getters`

Comment: @Michelle te sigue dando error de sintaxis?

Comment: no, porque?... ya funciona bien el programa completo :D

Answer (score 1):

A tu clase `Alumno` le falta asignar los valores de `nombre` y `matricula` en el constructor.

También, puedes o debes agregar un método `toString()` a tu clase alumnos para poder leer el mapa.

Observa que la lectura del mapa te muestra los datos como has definido el `toString`.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author cedano
 */
class Alumno {

private String nombre;
private int matricula;
private double calificaciones[];



Alumno(String nombre, int matricula, double calificaciones[]) {

    this.calificaciones = calificaciones;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.matricula = matricula;

}

String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

int getMat() {
    return matricula;
}

double[] getCalif() {
    return calificaciones;
}

void setCalif(double calif[]) {
    calificaciones = calif;
}

public String toString(){
     //return super.toString();
     return "("+this.nombre+":"+this.matricula+":"+Arrays.toString(this.calificaciones)+")";
    }


}
```

Luego puedes leer el mapa así:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Alumno> entry : alumnos.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println("KEY : "+ entry.getKey() +" \t VALUE : "+entry.getValue());
  }
```

Tendrás algo como esto:

```
KEY : 1      VALUE : (Pedro:1:[10.2, 2.3, 3.6, 4.6])
KEY : 2      VALUE : (Santiago:2:[9.2, 4.5, 10.3, 9.5])
```

---

Si no quieres implementar el método `toString`, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Alumno> entry : alumnos.entrySet()) {
    String strDatos=  "Nombre:"+entry.getValue().getNombre()
                    + " - Matricula: "+entry.getValue().getMat()
                    + " - Calificaciones:"+Arrays.toString(entry.getValue().getCalif());
   System.out.println(strDatos);
  }
```

El resultado será:

```
Nombre:Pedro - Matricula: 1 - Calificaciones:[10.2, 2.3, 3.6, 4.6]
Nombre:Santiago - Matricula: 2 - Calificaciones:[9.2, 4.5, 10.3, 9.5]
```

P.D.: A partir de Java 8, los mapas se leen así:

```
   alumnos.entrySet().stream().map((entry) -> "Nombre:"+entry.getValue().getNombre()
           + " - Matricula: "+entry.getValue().getMat()
           + " - Calificaciones:"+Arrays.toString(entry.getValue().getCalif())).forEachOrdered((strDatos) -> {
               System.out.println(strDatos);
});
```

### Para imprimir un alumno en específico

Preguntas por la `key` del Alumno usando `containsKey(keyDelAlumno)`, por ejemplo, si quieres los datos del Alumno 1:

```
int intUnAlumno=1;
if (alumnos.containsKey(intUnAlumno)) {
    Object esteAlumno = alumnos.get(intUnAlumno);
    System.out.println("Alumno (datos como están en toString) : " + esteAlumno);
 }
```

**Resultado:**

```
Alumno (datos como están en toString) : (Pedro:1:[10.2, 2.3, 3.6, 4.6])
```

Comment: Y si nadamas hay que imprimir un nombre en especifico con sus respectivas calificaciones? como le hago?

Comment: Es decir, no imprimir todo el contenido del mapa